# Plotting Error Bars on a Log Scale

Tags: graphics, plotting

I have a plot with `ErrorListPlot`

```
data = Sort@RandomReal[1, {10, 2}];
error = RandomReal[0.5, 10];
errorplot = ErrorListPlot[
  Partition[Riffle[data, ErrorBar /@ error], 2],
  Joined -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However, I would like to have it with the y-axis on a log scale. I can use `ListLogPlot` to get the log scale but this doesn't plot the errorbars.

```
logplot = ListLogPlot[
  data,
  PlotRange -> All,
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
  Joined -> True
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I tried `Show[logplot, errorplot, PlotRange->All]` to see if it would plot with the scale and ticks from the logplot but that didn't work right:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I also tried to take the `Ticks` from the logplot: `Show[errorplot, Ticks -> Ticks /. AbsoluteOptions@logplot]` but that just gives an error.

I tried to manually take the log of the data and then grab the tick-marks but that didn't work right

```
data = Sort@RandomReal[{10, 100}, {10, 2}];
error = RandomReal[20, 10];
logdata = Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], Log[10, data[[All, 2]]]}];
errorup = Log[10, data[[All, 2]] + error] - logdata[[All, 2]];
errordown = Log[10, data[[All, 2]] - error] - logdata[[All, 2]];
logerror = Log[10, error];
logplot = ListLogPlot[
  data,
  Joined -> True,
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}
  ]
errorlogplot = ErrorListPlot[
  Partition[
   Riffle[logdata, ErrorBar /@ Transpose[{errordown, errorup}]], 2],
  Joined -> True,
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}
  ]
errorlogplot2 = ErrorListPlot[
  Partition[
   Riffle[logdata, ErrorBar /@ Transpose[{errordown, errorup}]], 2],
  Joined -> True,
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
  Ticks -> (Ticks /. AbsoluteOptions@logplot)
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is there an easy way to do this?

On the log scale the error bars will appear asymmetrical.

Comment: Have you tried [LevelScheme](http://wnsl.physics.yale.edu/levelscheme/)? It's `CustomTicks` package is a superior alternative to trying to set it up by hand. The edition I have installed isn't functioning correctly, otherwise I would have posted it as an answer. But, it is worth a look.

Comment: Do you realize that 2 of your error bars on 1st plot have negative y-values? I guess it is an accident of making up a random data set, yet we should be aware of these logs of negative values.

Comment: @Vitaliy Kaurov, I realized that after I played with my random data more. I was originally working with a real dataset but it was simpler to post a line to generate random data then upload and link to the real data, however, my random data was slightly broken as you noticed.

Comment: Unfortunately horizontal error bars are not discussed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I always use the package [ErrorBarLogPlots](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/6747/). From the website:

> `ErrorBarLogPlots.m` is a package which adds log-scale plotting functions similar to the standard `ErrorListPlot` provided in Mathematica 6. The added functions are `ErrorListLogPlot`, `ErrorListLogLinearPlot`, and `ErrorListLogLogPlot`."

Comment: Strange...Once I write: Needs["ErrorBarLogPlots.m´"], I get the following error: Needs::cxt: Invalid context specified at position 1 in Needs[ErrorBarLogPlots.m\.b4]. A context must consist of valid symbol names separated by and ending with `. >> ... Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @AnastasiiaAnishchenko Just write Needs["ErrorBarLogPlots`"].

Comment: this doesn't work either...does one have to install anything in addition? I get this message: Needs::nocont: Context ErrorBarLogPlots` was not created when Needs was evaluated. >>

Comment: @AnastasiiaAnishchenko Hmm, I don't get this error. Have you installed the package? Here is the [link]( http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/6747/) . Download the zip file and install it, then retry the Needs command.

Comment: This solution may no longer work correctly in version 8 and above, as suggested in [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30535/245)

Comment: This runs in 11.3.0.0.  It is in my "init.m" file and one of the first packages i install on a new machine. Added this because the link to "this question" gave me a 404.

Answer (score 30):

### Without using the "ErrorBarPlots`" Package

```
dataX = Sort@RandomReal[1, 10];
dataY = RandomReal[{0.5, 1}, 10];
error = RandomReal[0.5, 10];
errorH = dataY + error;
errorL = dataY - error;
f[y_] := Transpose[{dataX, y}];

ListLogPlot[{f[errorH], f[errorL], f[dataY]}, 
            Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, 
            Joined -> {False, False, True}]
```

[image]

**Edit**

Following @rcollyer's suggestion

```
dataX = Sort@RandomReal[1, 10];
dataY = RandomReal[{0.5, 1}, 10];
error = RandomReal[0.5, 10];
f[y_] := Transpose[{dataX, y}];

PlusMinus[a_, b_] := {a + b, a - b, a};
plusMinList = Thread[PlusMinus[dataY, error]];

ePlot[plotFun_, dataX_, plusMinList_] :=
 plotFun[{
   f[plusMinList[[All, 1]]],
   f[plusMinList[[All, 2]]],
   f[plusMinList[[All, 3]]]},
  Filling -> {1 -> {2}},
  Joined -> {False, False, True}]
ePlot[ListLogPlot, dataX, plusMinList]
```

Comment: @rcollyer Thanks! _Filling_ is widely supported by almost all Plotting primitives. I use it always to draw error bars.

Comment: This could easily be transformed into a function that accepts the form `{_, PlusMinus[_,_}` and plots it on the plotting function of your choice: `ListPlot`, `ListLogPlot`, etc.

Comment: @rcollyer Done :)

Comment: I'd put `PlusMinus` inside of a `Block` to prevent corrupting ``Global` ``, and accept `d:{{_, PlusMinus[_,_]}..}`.

Comment: Nice! If more traditional error bars are desirable, options can be added: `ListLogPlot[..., PlotMarkers -> {"-", "-", "\[FilledCircle]"}]`

Comment: Thanks very much. I used your filling idea to create continuous filled error bounds: http://i.stack.imgur.com/wPvOR.png

Comment: @s0rce Nice plot!

Comment: @R.M Thanks! As a matter of fact I answered a more difficult one here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8032684/353410

Comment: Nice, but how can I draw horizontal error bars?

Answer (score 23):

**A one-liner solution** (see a bit below lengthy explanation)

This is a bit hacky solution, yet its simplicity prompted me to post it. Load package and make up a data set:

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
data = Sort@RandomReal[1, {10, 2}]; error = RandomReal[0.2, 10];

errorplot = ErrorListPlot[Partition[Riffle[data, ErrorBar /@ error], 2], 
            Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

**IMPORTANT:** *nothing goes below x-axis - not the data, not the error bars. Otherwise your log-scale will break - you cannot take log of negative numbers*.

Now lets take a look at the "guts" of the produced graphics:

```
errorplot // InputForm
```

[image]

`Line` graphics primitive (sometimes with `Offset`) applied to sets of points given by coordinates like `{x, y}`. You just need to replace all these pairs by `{x, Log@y}`. **Careful with `Offset`** - its 1st argument needs to be left a lone. Luckily for us it has an integer `0` so it is easy to avoid applying a pattern that distinguishes it from real numbers we need to deal with.

**So here is your one-liner solution:**

```
lerrorplot = errorplot /. {x_Real, y_Real} -> {x, Log@y}
```

[image]

Notice undesirable non-standard ticks on vertical axes (corresponding to log values). To check that it is indeed correct - compare versus `ListLogPlot`:

```
check = ListLogPlot[data, Joined -> True, Frame -> True, 
Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> {Thickness[.03], Orange, Opacity[.3]}];
Show[check, lerrorplot, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

A perfect match. Notice the ticks on vertical axes now are in traditional log-scale type (corresponding to original un-scaled data). Of course, your error bars got log-scaled too. *Warning*: be careful with these `ReplaceAll` type of solutions - you may be up to a surprise to what exactly is getting replaced. So always analyse your code to avoid unpleasant urprises.

Comment: +1, for a straightforward solution.  Looking at the code for `ErrorListPlot`, it uses `ReplaceAll` to effect its changes. Although it is a little more thorough and discriminating in it's approach.

Comment: Nice answer. BTW I liked the ripped-out look of your InputForm picture; Mathematica? It's ideal for pictures that have to convey the message "There's more of this, but that's not important".

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I use the software is called Snagit. It'd be cool to implement it in *Mathematica*.

Comment: Thanks very much, I ended up using the `ErrorBarLogPlot` package linked by @Markus Roellig since in the end I need a log-log plot. I tried `lerrorplot = errorplot /. {x_Real, y_Real} -> {Log@x, Log@y}` but I just got a green box.

Answer (score 5):

According to solution of Dr. Belisarius I wrote this more convenient code:

```
(* default options needed for error plot *)
Options[errListPlot] = {
   Filling -> {1 -> {2}},
   Joined -> {False, False, True},
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Black, Directive[Opacity[0.6], Blue]},
   FillingStyle -> Black,
   PlotMarkers -> {Graphics@Line[.04 {{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}], 
     Graphics@Line[.04 {{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}], ""}
   };
(*
plotFun - any ListPlot familly function;
data =List ( x, y, error );
opts - usual ListPlot options;
*)
errListPlot[plotFun_, data_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Block[{},
  plotFun[{{#[[1]], #[[2]] - #[[3]]} & /@ 
     data, {#[[1]], #[[2]] + #[[3]]} & /@ data, data[[;; , {1, 2}]]}, 
   opts, Sequence @@ Options[errListPlot]]
  ]
data = Table[{i, RandomReal[10], RandomReal[{0.1, 1}]}, {i, 1, 20}];
errListPlot[ListLogPlot, data, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x label", "y label"}, ImageSize -> 800, 
 BaseStyle -> {18, FontFamily -> "Arial"}]
```

[image: Resulting plot with error bars]
First I set necessary options for the plot with `Options[errListPlot]`. Then the plot function is defined with option pattern. Supplied options will be given to targeted List-XXX-Plot function and applied to the graphics.

Be careful, supplied option will overwrite default options from `Options[errListPlot]`. This can be useful if you do it right or catastrophic.

Comment: The question requested that the y-axis be logarithmic, not the x-axis.

Comment: This solution works for any combination of log, loglog, loglinear, linearlog plots. Example ListLogPlot: `errListPlot[ListLogPlot, data]`.

Comment: In that case, you may wish to edit your answer to include a figure that responds directly to the question.  Doing so would make your answer more useful to others.  Best wishes.

Answer (score 5):

In Mathematica 12, the `ErrorBarPlots` package was replaced by the built-in [Around](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Around.html) function and related methods.

Now it's possible to display errorbars on a logarithmic plot using only built-in core functions and the `ListLogPlot` function:

```
data = Sort@RandomReal[{2, 5}, {10, 2}];
error = RandomReal[0.5, 10];
toPlot = MapThread[({#1[[1]], Around[#1[[2]], #2]}) &, {data, 
    error}];
ListLogPlot[toPlot, Joined -> True, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this will always plot the absolute uncertainties. In Log-scale it is common to plot the relative error to avoid funny artifacts. ErrorBarLogPlots automatically took care of this. Does anybody found a similar functionality in V12?

Comment: @MarkusRoellig By relative uncertainty you mean ±5% for example? If so, you can use `Around[x, Scaled[0.05]]`.