# Plotting ErrorBars with a different style

Tags: plotting, packages

I would like to plot the error bars of `ErrorListPlot` with a different style than the points. I know of `ErrorBarFunction`, but then I have to recreate the automatic `ErrorBarFunction`...

Here is my current butt ugly hack (I draw the plot twice):

```
data = Table[{x, f[x], RandomReal[]}, {f, {Exp[2 #] &, Exp}}, {x, -5, 2, 0.2}];
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]

Show@{ErrorListPlot[data, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, PointSize -> 0., Opacity@0.5], 
   ImageSize -> Large],
  ListPlot[data[[All, All, {1, 2}]], 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, PointSize -> 0.015], 
   ImageSize -> Large]
  }
```

[image: example plot]

**What is a more elegant way of doing this?**

Something like:

```
ErrorListPlot[data, 
       PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, PointSize -> 0., Opacity@0.5], 
       ImageSize -> Large,
       ErrorBarFunction -> {Opacity@0.5,Automatic}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the sub-option `"LineOpacity"`  in `PlotStyle`:

```
ErrorListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, PointSize[Large], "LineOpacity" -> 0.2]]
```

[image]

It also works in version 9.0:

[image]

Answer (score 15):

You do not have to re-implement anything, just use a little chicanery:

```
ErrorListPlot[
 data,
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, PointSize -> 0.015],
 ImageSize -> Large,
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic,
 ErrorBarFunction -> (ErrorBarPlots`Private`ebarfun[##] /. l_Line :> {Opacity@0.5, l} &)
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Aaaa, very good. I think this s exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I have an "industrial strength" solution for creating your own plot marker function, but this was by far easier.

Comment: Hmm, now you have my curiosity. Care to post the `"industrial strength"` solution as a separate answer? Assuming it is not an industrial secret, of course:)

Comment: It's not, but it does require a bit more code ... I'll post it tonight. Time to go wake the munchkin from nap.

Comment: @Ajasja I finally [posted it](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/42580/52), but under a different question. :P

Comment: Err...I found no thing like "ebarfun" after searching document, however,`Names["ErrorBarPlots`Private`*"]` (*there is a "`" eaten*)do give many this kinds of all-lowercase-letter function/var. I wonder how did you find these mysterious magic function and their usage?

Comment: @Harry I cheated. I read the package file. But, you can also use ``?ErrorBarPlots`*`*`` to show all the internal symbols in the package.

Answer (score 13):

Here is an alternative you might like based on an [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3906/65) I got to a previous question of mine: [Plotting Error Bars on a Log Scale](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3897/plotting-error-bars-on-a-log-scale)

```
ClearAll[ePlot, ePlotFunc, plusMinusMean];
plusMinusMean[a_, b_] := {a + b, a - b, a};
ePlot[plotFun_, dataX_, plusMinList_, color_] := Block[{f},
  f[y_] := Transpose[{dataX, y}];
  plotFun[{
    f[plusMinList[[All, 1]]], f[plusMinList[[All, 2]]], 
    f[plusMinList[[All, 3]]]}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, 
   Joined -> {True, True, True}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0], Opacity[0], Darker@color}, 
   PlotMarkers -> {Graphics@{Disk[]}, 0.03}, 
   FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.2], color], Frame -> True, 
   Axes -> False]]


ePlotFunc[data_, color_] := 
 Module[{dataY, dataX, errorY, plusMinList}, 
  dataY = data[[All, 2]];
  dataX = data[[All, 1]];
  errorY = data[[All, 3]];
  plusMinList = Thread[plusMinusMean[dataY, errorY]];
  ePlot[ListPlot, dataX, plusMinList, color]]

colors = {Hue[0.67, 0.6, 0.6], Hue[0.85, 0.6, 0.6]};

data = Table[{x, f[x], RandomReal[]}, {f, {Exp[2 #] &, Exp}}, {x, -5, 
    2, 0.2}];

Show@MapThread[ePlotFunc, {data, colors}]
```

[image: example1]

I hope you might be able to adapt this to your needs, see another example:

[image: example2]

Comment: Pretty, +1. Which solution is it based on?

Comment: @rcollyer belisarius's answer (added link above).

Comment: Thanks, I should've been able to pick that out.

Comment: Your original code was not working (you've been a bit sloppy and forgot to define `PlusMinus` and `f`). I've fixed it now (with non conflicting names).

Comment: @Ajasja My mistake, thanks for the fixing the code.

Answer (score 7):

Points are stylled with `PlotStyle`, Lines with `ReplaceAll`:

```
ErrorListPlot[data,
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, PointSize -> 0.01], ImageSize -> Large
  ] /. x_Line :> {Opacity@.5, x}
```

*(it was Sequence[Opacity@.5,x] before rcollyer comment)*

It is not allways so short, in case of more objects in `Plot/Show` etc. one has to specify pattern more carefully.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this was my first idea. But it's not good enough. Also you have to specify the colors twice...

Comment: @Ajasja I've deleted `Epilog` version. This is better.. I think :)

Comment: While I gave you a +1, using `Sequence[Opacity@.5, x]` can lead to unintended consequences. It is better to use `{Opacity@.5, x}` so the format _only_ applies to `x`.

Comment: @rcollyer You are right, I was trying to be fancy and I forgot about basics. :)

Answer (score 3):

LevelScheme almost works, but outlines the plot markers with the same transparent fuzzy line, making the whole plot fuzzy.

[image: Example image]

```
Needs["LevelScheme`"]

dataScheme = data /. {x_, y_, e_} :> {x, ErrorValue[y, e]};

Figure[
 {
  Table[{
    SetOptions[DataLine, Color -> ColorData[1][i]],
    SetOptions[DataSymbol, SymbolShape -> "Circle", 
     FillColor -> ColorData[1][i], Color -> ColorData[1][i], 
     SymbolSize -> 6, Thickness -> 3, LineOpacity -> 0.5],

    DataPlot[
     dataScheme[[i]], Tag -> set[i]
     ]}
   , {i, 2}],

  DataLegend[{0.1, 0.95}, {{set[1], "Data"}, {set[2], "Data2"}}, 
   Length -> 10, Gap -> 5, FontSize -> 15, FontFamily -> "Arial"]

  },
 PlotRange -> {{-5, 2}, {-1, 10}}, ImageSize -> 72*{6, 3},
 Frame -> True
 ]
```