# Aligning axes labels on multiple plots

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to create some "publication quality" figures, but *Mathematica* is fighting me all the way. So my question is: **Should I switch to Origin?** Please help!

---

Well, all joking aside: I'm trying to create a multipanel figure. Here is an example:

```
p1 = Plot[100 Sin@x, {x, -5, 5}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"XXX", "YYY"}, LabelStyle -> Large, 
   ImageSize -> 400, ImagePadding -> {{100, 1}, {0, 10}}];
p2 = Plot[5 Sin@x, {x, -5, 5}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"XXX", "TTTT"}, LabelStyle -> Large, 
   ImageSize -> 400, ImagePadding -> {{100, 1}, {40, 0}}];
Column[{p1, p2}, Spacings -> 0]
```

[image: Example image]

So the real question is: **How can I align the TTTT and YYYY axes labels?**

I also tried using grid, with separate labels but then the TTTT is not centered on the axis, but is too low.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207569/wolfram-mathematica-y-axis-frame-labels-are-not-aligned) is related.

Comment: Possibly related: [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16802/is-there-an-option-to-change-the-space-distance-between-tick-labels-and-axes-lab/16807#16807)

Comment: @RodLm It is indeed (only searched google and this site). Inset may be the way to go.

Comment: For this [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26850/52), you used ``LevelScheme` ``. This is the type of thing it was built for.

Comment: @rcollyer Indeed! but I can't get rid of the blurry outline (assuming I would like to keep the error bars semi transparent).

Comment: Is this a new version of ``LevelScheme` ``? It's been about 8 months since I used it, and it was an older version.

Comment: @rcollyer I think it's the current version.

Comment: The problem is with different width of ticks labels. I have tired to make them equal by applying for example Panel[_ 60] but getting those ticks, replotting etc is quite a long code so I've left it because of lack of time. Also `Grid` solutions are shorter. But if one is determined to create such function and `DumpSave` it, it could be more usefull I think.

Answer (score 7):

Mark Caprio's LevelScheme is great for this stuff.  Overkill actually ....

```
Quiet@Needs["LevelScheme`LevelScheme`"]

(* plot the functions *)
p1 = Plot[100 Sin@x, {x, -5, 5}, Frame -> True, LabelStyle -> Large, 
   ImageSize -> 400, ImagePadding -> {{60, 50}, {0, Automatic}}];
p2 = Plot[5 Sin@x, {x, -5, 5}, Frame -> True, LabelStyle -> Large, 
   ImageSize -> 400, ImagePadding -> {{60, 50}, {Automatic, 0}}];

(* define grids *)
grd1 = Graphics[{Directive[Lighter@Gray, Thin],
    Line[{{-5, 0}, {5, 0}}],
    Line[{{0, -100}, {0, 100}}]
    }];
grd2 = Graphics[{Directive[Lighter@Gray, Thin],
    Line[{{-5, 0}, {5, 0}}],
    Line[{{0, -100}, {0, 100}}]
    }];

(* assemble figure *)
Figure[{
  Multipanel[{2, 1},
   XPanelSizes -> 1,
   YPanelSizes -> {.5, .5},
   XPlotRanges -> {-5, 5},
   YPlotRanges -> {{-100, 100}, {-5, 5}},
   XFrameLabels -> "XXXX",
   YFrameLabels -> {"YYYY", "TTTT"},
   Margin -> {{55, 5}, {45, 5 }},
   BufferB -> 5,
   BufferL -> 5
   ],
  FigurePanel[{1, 1}, ShowPanelLetter -> False],
  RawGraphics@p1,
  RawGraphics@grd1,
  FigurePanel[{2, 1}, ShowPanelLetter -> False],
  RawGraphics@p2,
  RawGraphics@grd2
  },
 ImageSize -> {300, 300}
 ]
```

[image: Level scheme graphics]

Comment: +1 I agree completely. I thought `RawGraphics` did'nt work work with `ListErrorPlot`, but it seems it works "well enough"   http://i.stack.imgur.com/eizr8.png (the plot markers for some reason al drawn all over the place)

Comment: Also, why ``Quiet@Needs["LevelScheme`LevelScheme`"]`` instead of just ``Needs["LevelScheme`"]``?

Comment: @Ajasja: I'm using an older version which loads (in 9.0) with warning messages.  Regarding your first comment, I would suggest examining your plot ranges.

Comment: @dws yes, I realize I could change the plot range. I just find it interesting that lines are clipped, but not plot markers.

Comment: Sorry to bump this with a not so related question, but when I run your code (@dwa) I get the errors `Scheme::prange: No value specified for option PlotRange.  Assuming default value {{0,1},{0,1}}.` and `Multipanel::lsargs: Missing or unexpected arguments in level scheme object Multipanel[{2,1},XPanelSizes->1,YPanelSizes->{0.5,0.5},...`. What is wrong?

Comment: @Sosi: I get no errors when copying the entire code block above to a fresh notebook and executing.

Comment: @dwa: I can't seem to get it straight, but the problem is certainly mine.

Comment: @Sosi: do the NB's supplied with LevelScheme run?  What  version of LevelScheme do you have installed?

Comment: @dwa I think my problem should be with the installation, though I followed the instructions in the documentation. I'm using v3.53. Maybe we can continue this in chat? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Sosi: There appears to be a 12 hour TZ difference which might make chat problematic.

Comment: For anyone using this solution now, the first command to be used should be ``Get["SciDraw`"]``

Answer (score 4):

I would like to do it with `Grid`:

```
p1 = Plot[100 Sin@x, {x, -5, 5},
          Frame -> True,
          LabelStyle -> Large,
          ImageSize -> 400, ImagePadding -> {{60, 50}, {0, Automatic}}];
p2 = Plot[5 Sin@x, {x, -5, 5},
          Frame -> True,
          LabelStyle -> Large,
          ImageSize -> 400, ImagePadding -> {{60, 50}, {Automatic, 0}}];
Grid[{{
       Rotate[Style["YYY", "Graphics", Large, RGBColor[0, 0, 0, .999]], π/2],
       Rotate[Style["TTTT", "Graphics", Large, RGBColor[0, 0, 0, .999]], π/2],
       ""},
      {p1, p2, Style["XXX", "Graphics", Large]}
     }\[Transpose],
     Spacings -> {0, 0}, ItemSize -> Full]
```

[image: grid alignment]

Comment: Yup, I tried that. But then TTTT is off center. Although in my case I did not label the X axes with a grid, so it was even more noticeable. A fake example here http://i.stack.imgur.com/gCEkH.png

Comment: @Ajasja I remember there is a question about this off-center issue. But I can't remember any keyword for now.. :(

Comment: @Ajasja OK my memory lapses.. It's about `FrameLabel` not printing completely.. But I think you can align your labels more easily with `Alignment` option of `Grid`.

Comment: @Ajasja Also you can use `Spacer[...]` to support any boxes.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about spacer.

Comment: @Ajasja You're welcome. :)

Answer (score 4):

In the end I used `Epilog` with `Text`. The downside of this approach is that the plot label style is not automatically picked up. I really have to learn to better use `LevelScheme` some day... (or `matplotlib`:)

```
p1=Plot[100 Sin@x,{x,-5,5},Frame->True,FrameLabel->{"XXX",""},LabelStyle->Large
    ,ImageSize->400,ImagePadding->{{100,1},{0,10}},PlotRangeClipping->False
    ,Epilog->{Text[Rotate[Style[#,Large],\[Pi]/2]&@"YYYY",Scaled[{-0.15,0.5}]]}];

p2=Plot[5 Sin@x,{x,-5,5},Frame->True,FrameLabel->{"XXX",""},LabelStyle->Large
    ,ImageSize->400,ImagePadding->{{100,1},{Automatic,0}},PlotRangeClipping->False
    ,Epilog->{Text[Rotate[Style[#,Large],\[Pi]/2]&@"YYYY",Scaled[{-0.15,0.5}]]}];

Column[{p1,p2},Spacings->0]
```

[image: Example image]

Answer (score 1):

## Method 1 `Rasterize` `FrameLabel`

---

Control the size with `ImagePad`, and need `Raterize` for `ImagePad`.

======================================================================Input 1

1. ```
    rasterizePad[x_, pad_: {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}] := 

     Rasterize[

      ImagePad[Rasterize[Style[ToString@x, FontFamily -> Times], 

        ImageSize -> 100], t = pad, Red]]

    frameLables11 = rasterizePad[XXX]; frameLables12 = 

     rasterizePad[YYY]; frameLables21 = rasterizePad[XXX];

    Manipulate[

     frameLables22 = rasterizePad[TTTT, {{0, 0}, {k, 0}}], {k, 0, 30, 1}]

    p11 = Plot[100 Sin@x, {x, -5, 5}, Frame -> True, 

       FrameLabel -> {frameLables11, frameLables11}, LabelStyle -> Large, 

       ImageSize -> 400, ImagePadding -> {{100, 1}, {0, 40}}];

    p12 = Plot[5 Sin@x, {x, -5, 5}, Frame -> True, 

       FrameLabel -> {frameLables21, Dynamic@frameLables22}, 

       LabelStyle -> Large, ImageSize -> 400, 

       ImagePadding -> {{100, 1}, {100, 0}}];

    Dynamic@Column[{p11, p12}, Spacings -> 0]
   ```

## Method 2 use `Graphics FrameLabel`

---

======================================================================Input 2

2. ```
    frameGraphics = 

      Graphics[{Text[Style["TTTT", FontSize -> 24], {0, 1}], {Opacity[0], 

         Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]}}, ImageSize -> {100, 50}];

    p21 = Plot[100 Sin@x, {x, -5, 5}, Frame -> True, 

       FrameLabel -> {"XXX", "YYY"}, LabelStyle -> Large, 

       ImageSize -> 500, ImagePadding -> {{120, 50}, {0, 0}}];

    p22 = Plot[5 Sin@x, {x, -5, 5}, Frame -> True, 

       FrameLabel -> {"XXX", frameGraphics}, LabelStyle -> Large, 

       ImageSize -> 500, ImagePadding -> {{120, 50}, {60, 0}}];

    Column[{p21, p22}, Spacings -> 0]
   ```

## Method 3(failed)

---

As @silvia mentioned in her comment of her answer about `Spacers`.

So I tried this:

I think I failed here in using `Sapcings`,`Column` and `Spacers`

======================================================================Input 3

3. ```
    p31 = Plot[100 Sin@x, {x, -5, 5}, Frame -> True, 

       FrameLabel -> {"XXX", 

         Column[{"YYY", ""}, Spacings -> 0, Frame -> True]}, 

       LabelStyle -> Large, ImageSize -> 500, 

       ImagePadding -> {{120, 50}, {0, 0}}];

    p32 = Plot[5 Sin@x, {x, -5, 5}, Frame -> True, 

       FrameLabel -> {"XXX", 

         Column[{"TTTT", Spacer[{0, 1}]}, Spacings -> 1, Frame -> True]}, 

       LabelStyle -> Large, ImageSize -> 500, 

       ImagePadding -> {{120, 50}, {60, 0}}];

    Column[{p31, p32}, Spacings -> 0]
   ```

Any Suggestions?

[image]