# message about string expected in pattern

Tags: string-manipulation

```
names=Select[(StringCases[list2=Names["System`*"],RegularExpression["[a-z]+"],IgnoreCase->True]//Flatten),MemberQ[list2,#]&];

namesReplaceRules=names/.x_String->(x->"`"<>x<>"`");
```

I found it will generate the `message`, but also gives the right result in this case.

> StringJoin::string: String expected at position 2 in `<>x<>`. >>

I can Use `Quiet` or Ignore the message, or Add one `ToString` to `x`

```
namesReplaceRules=names/.x_String->(x->"`"<>x<>"`");
```

Which is the right choice in such a case?

More elegant codes?

Comment: Please use descriptive titles for your questions instead of ["Little problem with X"](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A6648+title%3Aproblem)

Comment: I have closed this question as a duplicate.  That question gets into a deeper issue of infinite evaluation but up front the problem is the same, use of `Rule` rather than `RuleDelayed`, and it is even in the context of String operations.  If you disagree with this closure please respond to this comment.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard ok, no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I think this problem is related to the evaluation process of `Rule`. When performing a replacement with a named pattern (`x_String` in this case), you'd better use `RuleDelayed` rather than `Rule`:

```
names = Select[(StringCases[list2 = Names["System`*"], 
  RegularExpression["[a-z]+"], IgnoreCase -> True] // Flatten), 
   MemberQ[list2, #] &];

namesReplaceRules = names /. x_String :> (x -> "`" <> x <> "`");
```

Note that even if you use `Rule`, you can still get the right result, this is because `` x -> "`" <> x <> "`" `` will evaluate to itself with a error message. But if the rhs of `Rule` evaluate to something else, [something bad](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22917/unexpected-behavior-of-rule-matching-a-pattern/22919#22919) would happen.

Comment: nice+1, I mush have tried `RuleDelayed` incompletely. :(

Comment: How do you think my formatting here? Actually I like MrWizard's style one yellow blockquotes for output.
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26974/unexpected-result-a-compute-m-from-sort-m-a-compute

Comment: @HyperGroups I don't really know, I like Leonid Shifrin's [style](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-compile-effectively/1816#1816), with codes formatted neatly.

Comment: en, I learned that (*newline ==> newline*),fine. 
I added the input numbers for indicating possible Picture results, because rm-rf said that the image uploader would not be fixed in a short time. So I combine several picture results in one results to insert in the post more convinently. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26932/6648