# ListPlot - Conditional Coloring of PlotPoints

Tags: plotting, color

```
data = {5.0, 2.9, 9.9, 14.5, 6.8, 4.2};
mean = {2.2, 3.4, 8.1, 13.6, 7.5, 3.5};

ListPlot[{data, mean}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"data", "mean"}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]

I would like to color the points above mean green and below mean red.
The only solution I found is to use `Graphics`:

```
color = If[# > 0, Darker @ Green, Red] & /@ (data - mean);

Graphics[
 {
  PointSize@Large,
  Blue,
  Point @ Transpose[{Range@Length@mean, mean}],
  Transpose[{color, Point /@ Transpose[{Range@Length@data, data}]}]
  },
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
 Frame -> True,
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed]]
```

[image]

Is there a way to obtain a similar result with `ListPlot`?

Comment: This looks like a good application of [`DataListPlot`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/42580/52). If I get the time, I'll write it up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It think this might work for you:

```
ListPlot[
  {
   MapThread[Style[#1, If[#1 - #2 >= 0, Darker@Green, Red]] &, {data, mean}],
   mean
  },
  PlotLegends -> {"data", "mean"}, PlotRange -> {{0, 7}, Automatic},
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02], PlotTheme -> "Detailed"
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Astonishing! +1

Comment: never would have thought to try that, ! Is this a new feature?

Comment: @george2079 It *may* be, or at least I noticed this usage in the documentation for `ListPlot` for the first time in v. 10.3. Compare e.g. the [current docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html) with the [10.2 version](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/language/v10.2/ref/ListPlot.html) of the same page.

Comment: I would use `PlotMarkers` to better differentiate between the two data sets, but `ListPlot` uses `Inset` for `PlotMarkers` which means `Style` is not correctly applied. This is fixed by adding `Method -> {"OptimizePlotMarkers" -> False}` to the options. +1 for being simple.

Comment: nice. It works in 10.1 (undocumented).  The trick works with `Plot` too, `Plot[Style[x^2, Dashed], {x, -1, 1}]`

Comment: @rcollyer, reading your comment made me realize the right answer to [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/105574/9490) question.

Answer (score 4):

This an addendum to MarcoB's answer. I think for this plot it would be better to exert more control over `PlotLegends`. I suggest generating the legend like so:

```
With[{loColr = Red, hiColr = Darker@Green, mnColr = Orange},
  ListPlot[{
    MapThread[
      Style[#1, If[#1 - #2 >= 0, hiColr, loColr]] &, {data, mean}],
    mean},
    PlotLegends ->
      PointLegend[{hiColr, loColr, mnColr}, {"above mean", "below mean", "mean"}],
    PlotRange -> {{0, 7}, Automatic},
    PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02],
    PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]]
```

[image: plot]