# Asymmetric X and Y error bars on ListLogPlot

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

The wonderful error bar log plots package `ErrorBarLogPlots` from `V6` no longer positions labels correctly (since `v9` or maybe `v8`) so I used the same function with `Prolog` to place a list of labels.

Then in `v10 beta` `PlotRangePadding` no longer works either and I can't find a work around for that, so I tried to go back to basics and use the very elegant solution by [Belisarius'](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/193/belisarius) et.al in:

[Plotting Error Bars on a Log Scale](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3897/plotting-error-bars-on-a-log-scale)

I was able to modify this to make asymmetric $Y$ error bars, then I tried to add $X$-errors and got tied up in knots with the `Joined` and `Filling` commands.

**The aim** is to plot a set of $5$ lists of `xy` values, `{xy, xyP, xyM, xPy, xMy}` where `P` and `M` refer to the plus and minus error of the $x$ or $y$ value preceding it, with a `Filling` / `Joined` statement that joins the first point to the other 4 points.

Ideally the plot symbols should also switch between vertical and horizontal bars for the $x$ and $y$ error points and something else for the $x, y$ point. (I asked Support about including an `errorlistlogplot` command in *Mathematica* but I expect it won't make it into `v10`).

The lines below generate and plot the `5` sets of points. Is there a straightforward combination of `Filling` / `Joined` statements to achieve this?

```
SeedRandom[1234]
dataX = Sort@RandomReal[{0.5, 1}, 10];
dataY = RandomReal[{0.5, 1}, 10];
{errorYP, errorYM, errorXP, errorXM} = RandomReal[.5, {4, 10}];
dataYP = dataY + errorYP;
dataYM = dataY - errorYM;
dataXP = dataX + errorXP;
dataXM = dataX - errorXM;
xy = Transpose[{dataX, dataY}];
xyP = Transpose[{dataX, dataYP}];
xyM = Transpose[{dataX, dataYM}];
xPy = Transpose[{dataXP, dataY}];
xMy = Transpose[{dataXM, dataY}];

ePlot[plotFun_, data_] := plotFun[data, Filling -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All,
                                        Joined -> {False, False, False, False, False}];

ePlot[ListLogPlot, {xy, xyP, xyM, xPy, xMy}]
```

[image]

Comment: I suppose you can't ask for solution on V10 since it is not released yet. So you want the solution for nonsymetric errorbars in x and y axis without `PlotRangePadding`?

Comment: Yes v9. The PlotRangePadding command works in V10 with the inbuilt ListLog plots etc, but not with plots created using the external package ErrorBarLogPlots. So a v9 solution is likely a v10 solution also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

README: *This answer is not correct scientifically, I just transformed error bars to log scale instead of doing a correct error propagation. Didn't have time to fix it yet :(*

---

Here's a minimal example:

```
data = {{20, 100}, {30, 10}, {100, 1000}, {500, 1000}};
xer = {{10, 10}, {20, 300}, {50, 50}, {100, 200}};
yer = {{50, 50}, {5, 50}, {100, 500}, {300, 100}};

errorPlot[#, data, xer, yer] & /@ {ListPlot, ListLogPlot, 
                                   ListLogLogPlot, ListLogLinearPlot};
```

[image]

#### Code:

```
errorPlot[plot_, data_, xer_, yer_] := With[{
       tr = Transpose@data,
       arrow = Graphics[{Red, Line[{{0, 1/2}, {0, -1/2}}]}]},
      Module[{PlusMinus, limits, limitsRescaled, dataRescaled, lines, scale},
    
       scale = plot /. {ListPlot -> {# &, # &}, ListLogPlot -> {# &, Log}, 
                        ListLogLogPlot -> {Log, Log}, ListLogLinearPlot -> {Log, # &}};
   
       PlusMinus[a_, b_] := {a - b[[1]], a + b[[2]]};
       limits =  MapThread[MapThread[PlusMinus, {#, #2}] &,
                           {tr, {xer, yer}}];
   
       limitsRescaled = MapThread[Compose, {scale, limits}];   
       dataRescaled = MapThread[Compose, {scale, tr}];
   
       lines = Flatten[
                MapAt[Reverse, 
                      MapThread[{{#2[[1]], #}, {#2[[2]], #}} &, 
                                {Reverse@dataRescaled, limitsRescaled}, 2], 
                      {2, ;; , ;;}], 1];   
   
        Show[
         plot[data, PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize@7, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
                    BaseStyle -> 18, ImageSize -> 500],
         Graphics[{Arrowheads[{{-.02, 0, arrow}, {.02, 1, arrow}}], Thick, Arrow[lines]}]
         ,
         PlotRange -> ({Min[#], Max[#]} & /@ Transpose@Flatten[lines, 1])]]]
```

Comment: This works great with Show[errorPlot[ListLogPlot,data[[#]],xer[[#]],yer[[#]]]&/@Range[Length[data]] for plotting multiple series on the same plot. To apply different formatting for each series we can pass a list of #'d formatting options. I wasn't able to figure out how to arrange the 'data' and err lists to pass multiple data sets in one command (multiple series on one plot without Show); some form of Transpose[data,{?,?}], and Transpose[xer,{?,?}]. Would that be more efficient than using Show to get multiple series on one plot? Great solution either way.

Comment: @DrBubbles I'll try to make it more usefull. I will tell you when I'm done ;)

Comment: I moved the arrow heads inside the plot command to add multiple data sets with Tooltips: Show[plot[Tooltip[data[[#]], ttips[[#]]] & /@ Range[Length[data]], 
  PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize@7, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
  BaseStyle -> 18, ImageSize -> 500, 
  Prolog -> {Arrowheads[{{-.02, 0, arrow}, {.02, 1, arrow}}], Thick, 
    Arrow[lines]}], 
 PlotRange -> ({Min[#], Max[#]} & /@ Transpose@Flatten[lines, 1])] and called the function with errorPlot[plot_, data_, xer_, yer_, ttips_] and multiple data sets. Show overplots the multiple series with tooltips but only one set of error bars.

Comment: Sorry, I can't format the comments properly.

Comment: @Kuba It would be great if the code could be modified to accommodate also without x axis error bars case.

Comment: @AlGuy I must say it is very unlikely that I will make an edit here in a near future but if you want to, feel free to improve this answer.