# Adding graphics primitives to log plots

Tags: plotting, graphics, logarithmic-scale

I am making `ListLogLog` plots with polygons in the `Prolog` and lines in the `Epilog`, and I want to know how to make sure that the polygons and lines are being plotted consistently. One method that I know gives me lines with the right shape is to have

```
ListLogLogPlot[
 PlotRange -> {{.01, 10}, {10^-10, 10^-5}},
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 FrameTicks -> {
   {
    Automatic
    ,
    Automatic},
   {Automatic
    ,
    Automatic}},
 Prolog -> {
   Style[Polygon[Log[PLSND]], Lighter[Gray, .45], Opacity[1]]
   },
 Epilog -> {Style[Polygon[Log[10^Data]]]}]
```

`PLSND` is a list of points given in `(x,y)`, while `Data` is a list of points given in `(Log10[x], Log10[y])`.

My concern is that the `PLSND` and `Data` lines/polygons will be plotted with incorrect scaling relative to any other lists I give in the standard format. I have tried using `Log10` instead of `Log`, or `Log[Exp[Data]]`, but neither of these substitutions displays a line on my graph.

Comment: Keep in mind that when you post a minimal working example it will be easier for others to provide a solution. E.g. why do we have to make up `PLSND` and `DATA`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
data = Table[PartitionsQ[n], {n, 50}];
epilog = {EdgeForm@Thick, FaceForm@None, Rectangle[{20, 500}, {40, 2000}]};

ListPlot[data, Epilog -> epilog]

ListLogPlot[data, 
 Epilog -> (epilog /. {x_, y_?NumericQ} :> {x, Log[y]})]

ListLogLogPlot[data, 
 Epilog -> (epilog /. {x_, y_?NumericQ} :> Log@{x, y})]
```

[image]

Closely related topics:

- [Asymmetric X and Y error bars on ListLogPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42144/5478)
- [Plotting Error Bars on a Log Scale](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3897/5478)

Comment: Thank you, this confirms that the polygons scale properly, but why is it that just applying `Log` to the particular coordinates rather than `Log10` gives the correct result?

Comment: @Jordan Log is a natural logarithm, it is used for those plots.

Comment: Why not `NumericQ` instead of `NumberQ`?

Comment: @kirma without any specific reason, will replace it to make it more general.