# RegionPlot with LogScale

Tags: plotting, regions, logarithmic-scale

I would like to have my RegionPlot with logarithmic scale in x and y.

My code looks like

```
plot3 = RegionPlot[
  f3[y]/x > constant && 
   1000 < y < maximum, {x, 
   0 , 10^4}, {y,  10^(3), 
   maximum}, BoundaryStyle -> Dashed, 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.3, Green]]
Export["plot3.pdf", plot3]

plot2 = RegionPlot[
  f2[y]/x > constant && 
  0.1 <=  y <=  10^(3), {X, 
   0 , 10^4}, {Y, 0.1, 
   10^(3), BoundaryStyle -> Dashed, 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.3, Yellow]]
Export["plot2.pdf", plot2]


plot1 = RegionPlot[
  F1[Y]/X > constant && 
   y <= 0.1 , {x, 0 , 
   10^4}, {y, 0 , 0.1}, 
  BoundaryStyle -> Dashed, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.3, Blue]]
Export["plot1.pdf", plot1]


Show[plot1, plot2, plot3, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10^4}, {0, MAX}}]
```

With this code I get 4 plots, but each with a linear axes scaling. But I would like to have at least the last one i.e.

```
Show[plot1, plot2, plot3, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 10^4}, {0, MAX}}]
```

with a LogLogScale.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As someone else here mentioned there are no `Log` and `LogLog` versions of `RegionPlot`, so you can make them yourself.  The answer above relies on the user being able to apply the Log function to the input in the correct fashion, but it isn't always obvious which arguments or variables should be given the `Log` function in the argument, and which should have their plotting ranges scaled.  For example, it's not *immediately* clear to me how to do the same thing with this simple `RegionPlot`,

```
RegionPlot[x^2 + (y - 1)^3 < 2 && y > 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 2.5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Even if we figured out how to apply the proper scaling to the arguments and plot ranges, then we have to apply the scaling to the tick marks, using one of the methods described [in this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/113560/9490).

I think a better solution is to use the built-in capabilities of `ListLogPlot` and `ListLogLogPlot` to do the scaling for us.  All we need to do is to extract the points and the polygons from the `RegionPlot` and feed them into the appropriate log plotting function.  This comes with help from [Heike](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5266/9490) and [Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/102614/9490),

```
logRegionPlot[rplot_] := Module[{pts, pgon},
  pts = Cases[Normal@rplot, Line[a__] :> a, Infinity];
  pgon = {EdgeForm[], 
    Directive[RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], 
     AbsoluteThickness[1.6], Opacity[0.3]], 
    Cases[Normal@rplot, Polygon[_], Infinity]};
  ListLogPlot[pts,
   Joined -> True,
   Frame -> True,
   PlotRange -> All,
   AspectRatio -> 1,
   Axes -> False,
   PlotStyle -> ColorData[1][1],
   Epilog -> (pgon /. {x_, y_?NumericQ} :> {x, Log@y})]
  ]
```

and

```
logLogRegionPlot[rplot_] := Module[{pts, pgon},
  pts = Cases[Normal@rplot, Line[a__] :> a, Infinity];
  pgon = {EdgeForm[], 
    Directive[RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], 
     AbsoluteThickness[1.6], Opacity[0.3]], 
    Cases[Normal@rplot, Polygon[_], Infinity]};
  ListLogLogPlot[pts,
   Joined -> True,
   Frame -> True,
   PlotRange -> All,
   AspectRatio -> 1,
   Axes -> False,
   PlotStyle -> ColorData[1][1],
   Epilog -> (pgon /. {x_, y_?NumericQ} :> Log@{x, y})]
  ]
```

(**edit**: this was added by request)

```
loglinearRegionPlot[rplot_] := Module[{pts, pgon},
  pts = Cases[Normal@rplot, Line[a__] :> a, Infinity];
  pgon = {EdgeForm[],
    Directive[RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798],
     AbsoluteThickness[1.6], Opacity[0.3]],
    Cases[Normal@rplot, Polygon[_], Infinity]};
  ListLogLinearPlot[pts,
   Joined -> True, Frame -> True,
   PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1,
   Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> ColorData[1][1], 
   Epilog -> (pgon /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :> {Log@x, y})]]
```

So it is a simple matter to apply this to the region above,

```
logRegionPlot@
 RegionPlot[x^2 + (y - 1)^3 < 2 && y > 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 2.5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another example,

```
rplot = RegionPlot[{Exp[Abs[x]] <= y <= 100}, {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 120}]
{logRegionPlot@rplot,
 logLogRegionPlot@rplot,
 loglinearRegionPlot@rplot}
```

[image]

The only problem is that I can't figure out how to extract multiple regions from the `RegionPlot` and maintain their distinct colors.

Answer (score 6):

There is no [`LogRegionPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogRegionPlot.html) or [`LogLogRegionPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogLogRegionPlot.html), so if you want to make one you'll have to do the scaling yourself, and then supply the correct tick marks yourself using the undocumented (and sometimes poorly behaved) `` Charting`ScaledTicks `` function:

```
{RegionPlot[Exp[Abs[x]] <= y <= 100, {x, -6, 6}, {y, 0, 120}],
 RegionPlot[
  Log@Exp[Abs[x]] <= y <= Log@100, {x, -6, 6}, {y, 0, Log@120}, 
    FrameTicks -> {{Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}], None}, Automatic}]}
```

[image]

Another possibility would be to use a `Method` option within `RegionPlot`. This option is just as undocumented as the `` Charting`ScaledTicks `` one, but it is accepted by the syntax highlighter (in fact, a "ScalingFunctions" option is automatically generated by any `RegionPlot`, as one can verify by looking at the `InputForm` for one such plot).

For instance:

```
{
 RegionPlot[Exp[Abs[x]] <= y <= 100, {x, -6, 6}, {y, 0, 120}],
 RegionPlot[
  Log@Exp[Abs[x]] <= y <= Log@100, {x, -6, 6}, {y, 0, Log@120},
  Method -> "ScalingFunctions" -> {Log, Exp}
 ]
}
```

generates the same output as the one obtained above.

Comment: Jason, notice however that you are doing the scaling manually here, which is *not* how `ScalingFunctions` would normally work. I think the only thing `ScalingFunctions` accomplishes here is adding a Ticks directive using ``Charting`ScaledTicks``. For instance, you get more or less the same result by adding that in by hand: ``RegionPlot[Log@Exp[Abs[x]] <= y <= Log@100, {x, -6, 6}, {y, 0, Log@120}, FrameTicks -> {{Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}], None}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]``.

Comment: @MarcoB - definitely true!  The answer to the question "How can I make a RegionPlot with a log scale?"  is that you have to do it yourself  :-D

Comment: Another possibility would be to use `Method -> "ScalingFunctions" -> {Log, Exp}` within the `RegionPlot` to obtain the scaled ticks. You still have to do the logarithmic scaling by hand, and this option is just as undocumented as far as I can tell, but it is accepted by the syntax highlighter (in fact, a "ScalingFunctions" option is automatically generated by any `RegionPlot`! that's how I noticed it).

Comment: @MarcoB that's great, thanks for catching it.  I have to run for the day, so if you would like to edit and change it, great, if not I will do so tomorrow.  Always better to use options that aren't in red