# Inequality in RegionPlot with LogLinear scale

Tags: plotting, inequalities, logarithmic-scale

I want to plot a RegionPlot in LogLinear scale.
If I try with a simple linear scale,

```
pl = RegionPlot[T < (15.4)^(1/n)*0.001, {T, 0.001, 1000}, {n, 0, 4}, 
Ticks -> {ScientificForm[#], Automatic}, AxesLabel -> {T, n},
Method -> "ScalingFunctions" -> {Automatic, Automatic}]
```

I obtain this plot (which seems to be ok)

[image]

If I try to switch the x-axis to a Log10 scale in this way:

```
pl = RegionPlot[T < (15.4)^(1/n)*0.001, {T, 0.001, 1000}, {n, 0, 4}, 
Ticks -> {ScientificForm[#], Automatic}, AxesLabel -> {T, n},
Method -> "ScalingFunctions" -> {"Log10", Automatic}]
```

I obtain the ugly picture

[image]

which is definitely not what I want.

If I try to use the suggestion provided in [RegionPlot with LogScale](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113556/regionplot-with-logscale) using

```
loglinearRegionPlot[rplot_] := Module[{pts, pgon},
pts = Cases[Normal@rplot, Line[a__] :> a, Infinity];
pgon = {EdgeForm[],
    Directive[RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798],
     AbsoluteThickness[1.6], Opacity[0.3]],
    Cases[Normal@rplot, Polygon[_], Infinity]};
  ListLogLinearPlot[pts,
   Joined -> True, Frame -> True,
   PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1,
   Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> ColorData[1][1], 
   Epilog -> (pgon /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :> {Log@x, y})]]

pl = loglinearRegionPlot@
RegionPlot[T < (15.4)^(1/n)*0.001, {T, 0.001, 1000}, {n, 0, 4},
Ticks -> {ScientificForm[#], Automatic},
AxesLabel -> {T, n}]
```

I obtain

[image]

which is pretty close to what I want, but it doesn't show a nice hyperbole, but those sharpy and polygonal lines and a rectangular shape between 0.01 and 0.1...

What can I do?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that [`ScalingFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions) are not supported by [`RegionPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot). So, one idea is to include the transformation in your inequality (that is, replace `T` with `10^T`) and plot from `Log10[.001]` to `Log10[1000]`. This will produce the desired shape, but the ticks will be wrong. So, you will need to provide the correct ticks as well:

```
RegionPlot[
    10^T < (15.4)^(1/n) 0.001,
    {T, -3, 3}, 
    {n, 0, 3},
    AxesLabel -> {T,n},
    FrameTicks->{
        Automatic,
        {Charting`ScaledTicks["Log10"],Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Log10,10^#&}]}
    },
    PlotRange->All
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a way to change the shape of the plot from square to rectangular?

Comment: @Lele Add an AspectRatio option, e.g., `AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio`.