# How to add Arrow in plot with text next to it?

Tags: plotting

How do you add an arrow as in the picture, with some text next to it?

```
 LogLogPlot[{x^-2, x^-3}, {x, 0.001, 100}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

I tried with:

```
  Show[LogLogPlot[{x^-2, x^-3}, {x, 0.001, 100}, PlotRange -> Full], 
  Graphics[Arrow[{{0.01, 0.01}, {10, 10^6}}]]]
```

[image]

Why is the arrow going so high? Aren't the starting and ending points defined well?

Comment: Have you seen `Arrow[]`, `Text[]`, and `Epilog`?

Comment: @J.M. I have seen Arrow[] but didn't get what I wanted. I will look for Epilog and let you know

Comment: "didn't get what I wanted" - then, can you edit your question to explain why you had trouble with `Arrow[]`?

Comment: Use `Arrow[Log@{{0.01, 0.01}, {10, 10^6}}]` underlying coordinates are different.

Comment: In general: [lines or polygons in log plots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102613/5478)

Comment: It appears that at the end the linked topic answers your question, thus I marked it a duplicate. Let me know if you disagree or if there is anything to clarify.