# How to plot data with error bars on a log scale in Mathematica 9?

Tags: plotting, data

I have data in the form

```
 d={{x1,y1,dy1},{x2,y2,dy2},..{xn,yn,dyn}};
```

so the error bars are different for each coordinate pair. I want to plot on a logarithmic x-scale.
Since I use Mathematica 9 the old library from Mathematica 6 with Errorlogplot does not seem to work.
Kind regards
  Benjamin

Comment: Although the question asked specifically about version 9, in version 12, there's a better alternative as shown in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/195463/27171).

Answer (score 4):

Try the `ErrorBarLogPlots` package, which you can download [here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/6747/):

Throw it in the folder that opens after evaluating this:

```
SystemOpen@FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications"}]
```

Then load the package in Mathematica and go:

```
<< ErrorBarLogPlots`

ErrorListLogLogPlot[{{1, 2, 2}, {2, 3, 1}, {4, 4, 2.6}, {9.5, 12, 5}},
  Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> 0.1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Other plots available in this package are:

- `ErrorListLogLinearPlot`
- `ErrorListLogPlot`

Comment: I downloaded it here http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/6747/  and did as you said. When I evaluate the notebook it says installation failed! Does not seem to work with Mathematica 9 + Windows 8 ( probably has nothing to do with windows 8).

Comment: @neverender What do you mean by `evaluate the notebook`? Did you do anything other than using `Get` (`<<`)? I do have Mathematica 9 be it on Win7.

Comment: had to give the the installer file administrative rights, my bad. thank you very much!

Comment: @neverender Just moving the .m file from the .zip file to the directory described above would have been sufficient. I should have described that better.

Comment: Note, however, that the error bars produced by ErrorListLogLogPlot are symmetric, which (at least in my opinion) is unexpected on a logarithmic scale. If this aspect is of importance, the error bars could always be constructed manually, e.g. by (ab)using ErrorListPlot:
dat={{1,2,1},{2,3,1},{4,4,2.6},{9.5,12,5}}
ListLogLogPlot[
 dat[[All, 1 ;; 2]],
 Prolog -> ErrorListPlot[
    With[{x = Log[#1], y = Log[#2]}, {{x, y}, 
        ErrorBar[{Log[#2 - #3] - y, Log[#2 + #3] - y}]}] & @@@ dat, 
    PlotRange -> All, Axes -> False][[1]],
 PlotRange -> {{0.5, 10}, {0.5, 50}}
 ]

Comment: @dakta Symmetry in error bars on a log scale are not always wrong. If one takes logs (or the square root or some other monotonic transformation) and finds the resulting data/residuals approximately symmetric, then symmetry of error bars on the transformed scale is the appropriate display.

Comment: The relative error is sometimes used to force error bar symmetry in transformed data rather than using absolute error. Anyone know if the above package does this? 
http://faculty.washington.edu/stuve/log_error.pdf