# ErrorListLogPlot gives wrong error bars on log scale

Tags: plotting, bugs, logarithmic-scale

From [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3897/plotting-error-bars-on-a-log-scale) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/49123/how-to-plot-data-with-error-bars-on-a-log-scale-in-mathematica-9) post I learned how to use `ErrorListLogPlot` and its family to add error bars on top of a list of mean values. However, consider this simple example:

```
Needs["ErrorBarLogPlots`"]

ErrorListLogPlot[{{1, 0.6}, {2, 0.5}, {3, 1.5}}, Joined -> True, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0.1, 5}}, 
GridLines -> {{}, {0.4, 1.5, 1.6, 2.5, 4.5}}]
```

[image: output]

where `{1, 2, 3}` are mean values and `{0.6, 0.5, 1.5}` are the associated standard errors. I added `GridLines` to indicate the positions where the end points of error bars are supposed to be located. It is clear from the plot above that the gridlines and end points do not intersect (on Mathematica 9), so the error bars must be wrong. I wonder whether something can be fixed in the `ErrorBarLogPlots` package. Note that the following examples, including built-in `ErrorListPlot`,  give correct error bars (either on linear or log scale):

```
ErrorListPlot[{{1, 0.6}, {2, 0.5}, {3, 1.5}}, Joined -> True, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0.1, 5}}, 
GridLines -> {{}, {0.4, 1.5, 1.6, 2.5, 4.5}}] 

ListPlot[{{1, 2, 3}, {0.4, 1.5, 1.5}, {1.6, 2.5, 4.5}}, 
Joined -> {False, True, True}, PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0.1, 5}}, 
GridLines -> {{}, {0.4, 1.5, 1.6, 2.5, 4.5}}, 
Filling -> {2 -> {3}}]

ListLogPlot[{{1, 2, 3}, {0.4, 1.5, 1.5}, {1.6, 2.5, 4.5}}, 
Joined -> {False, True, True}, PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0.1, 5}}, 
GridLines -> {{}, {0.4, 1.5, 1.6, 2.5, 4.5}}, 
Filling -> {2 -> {3}}]
```

Comment: The explanation to this problem is summarized [here](https://faculty.washington.edu/stuve/log_error.pdf). The thing is basically that error-bars do not transform (when you pass to log-scale) taking logarithm at the end of the bars, relative error is needed instead of the absolute one. (sorry for the bad english)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75160/discussion-on-question-by-leo-fang-errorlistlogplot-gives-wrong-error-bars-on-lo).